# Что делать если не отображаеться Canvas с кнопками в Unity 2D Android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, 2d

Помогите не могу решить вопрос уже 30 минут.

Comment: Vorner, добро пожаловать на сайт !!! ознакомьтесь как задать качественный вопрос на ресурсе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704387/unity-2d-how-to-set-touch-button